# What's the starting Exhaustion score for PCs in a new game?

Tags: character-creation, dont-rest-your-head

I've looked through the manual three times for starting Exhaustion scores and can't locate anything definitive. I've found a few places that might imply Exhaustion starts at 0, but nothing that comes right out and says so.

**What Exhaustion score do PCs start with at the beginning of a DRYH campaign?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I agree it's not clear in the manual, player's are supposed to normally start out with 0 exhaustion, as evidenced [here](http://www.evilhat.com/download/dryh-demo-kit.pdf), in the demo kit:

> Start all the protagonists off at an Exhaustion level of 2, rather than zero.